# How to filter pods based on status in k9s

Tags: kubernetes

Often there is more than one search result returned from `/` filter command which is confirm by pressing `Enter`. Then I can navigate the results, but have no way to filter based on data displayed e.g. **Status** or **CPU**.

QUESTION: Is this possible? If so, what I need to do to achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 28):

I don't think it's possible to filter search result, but you can sort them, which can be helpful in most cases. For example:

- SHIFT+C sorts by CPU
- SHIFT+M sorts by MEMORY
- SHIFT+S sorts by STATUS
- ...

Answer (score 6):

You can filter results using `/` just like with `:`

As @dgebert said for sorting use `SHIFT` + first letter of keyword to sort by

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this where replace `ImagePullBackOff` with filter of your need

```
kubectl get pod -o=json | jq '.items[]|select(any( .status.containerStatuses[]; .state.waiting.reason=="ImagePullBackOff"))|.metadata.name'
```